# I want to know which implementaion of arp is used in Ubuntu 10.10?

Tags: application-development

Also I am a techie and wanna know how to join the developer network of Ubuntu?

Answer (score 2):

The implementation of ARP in Linux is part of the kernel.

The kernel in 10.10 is kernel version 2.6.35 ; you can get this from git repositories.

The [kernel.org repositories](http://git.kernel.org/?p=linux/kernel/git/stable/linux-stable.git;a=summary) tend to be faster than the [Ubuntu ones](http://kernel.ubuntu.com/git) - I would clone from kernel.org, and then pull any branches you want from the Ubuntu repositories.

As for joining the Ubuntu developers ; hang around on Ubuntu channels on the [FreeNode IRC](http://freenode.net) network, sign up for a [Launchpad](http://launchpad.net) account, find a project which you think needs improving, and contribute. You don't have to do great things - just _some_thing. A whole of little things come together to make something great.